# The classical Krein-Rutman theorem

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, reference-request

The classical Krein-Rutman theorem states that any positive compact linear endomorphism $T:X \to X$ on a Banach space $X$ with positive spectral radius $r(T)$ has an eigenvalue $r(T)$ with a positive eigenvector. Papers and textbooks seem to write off the theorem as "standard" and "well-known", but I have not been able to locate any exposition with a proof of the theorem.

Is there a reference (preferably a textbook) including the statement *and* the proof of the theorem? (The original paper of Krein and Rutman appears to be in Russian, which I cannot read.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

["Topological Vector Spaces"](http://books.google.com/books?id=9kXY742pABoC&printsec=frontcover&dq=topological+vector+spaces&cd=1#v=onepage&q&f=false) by  Helmut Schaefer contains a thorough treatment of the classical Krein-Rutman theorem for compact positive operators in an ordered Banach space along with several generalizations to the case of a locally convex space with a cone. See Section 2 of the Appendix, *Pringsheim's Theorem and Its Consequences*. 
.

Answer (score 7):

For Banach *lattices*, a statement and a sketch of the proof can be found in Abramovich and Aliprantis's article "Positive operators" in the Handbook of the Geometry of Banach Spaces: see [Google books excerpt](http://books.google.com/books?id=1A7ppEZPXEIC&pg=PA99&lpg=PA99&dq=krein-rutman+theorem&source=bl&ots=zyW3ltNHXY&sig=1fe-zsyxpWpgt6CISRJb3VRC3iQ&hl=en&ei=1B_5TeKYAorYiALQnfz9DA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=7&ved=0CEgQ6AEwBjgK#v=onepage&q=krein-rutman%20theorem&f=false)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a paper with a proof that is available online:
http://www.mat.umk.pl/c/document_library/get_file?uuid=9019c4ed-5803-4427-b32a-4c64f6b1d83a&groupId=671

Comment: The link is broke. Could you please write out the full reference which is independent of a link and post a new working link? Thank you.

Comment: No. I do not remember that seven year later!